# TimePicker JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using a JQUERY Time Picker by [Jon Thornton](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/) for my PHP reservation system with disableTimeRanges. My time ranges are from my database, which I put in arrays and I use AJAX to get my time ranges from my PHP file.

```
$('#Ttime').timepicker({ 
  'timeFormat': 'h:i A'
  'disableTimeRanges': unavailableTime 
});

$("#Ttime").focus(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '../admin/thname.php',
                data: "q="+id,
                dataType: 'json', 
                async : false,
                success: function(data){
                  unavailableTime = data;
                }
            });
        });
```

It all works but when I try to put MAX/MIN Time, my DisableTimeRanges doesn't work. It's like the codes are overlapping or having conflicts with each other.

```
                    $('#Ttime').timepicker({ 
                            'minTime': '2:00am',
                            'maxTime': '2:00pm',
                    });
```

Can anyone please help me with this problem ?

Comment: are u facing this problm after the ajax call..??

Comment: no sir, my Ajax doesn't work at all when I try to insert MAX/MIN Time.